# Eclipse faceted project metadata file could not be read

Tags: eclipse

Every now and then, I get this error in one of my Eclipse projects:

> Faceted project metadata file "/project/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml" could not be read.

This is a team project using Git. The ".settings" directory does not exist at all.

I'm not sure what project "facets" in Eclipse really are. Does anyone know what this error means or how to fix it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I resolved it this time by re-importing the Maven project. This recreated the .settings directory and eliminated the error.

Comment: Thank you it worked for me! Damned eclipse and its senseless errors this way is impossible to work...

Answer (score 37):

Right click the project in eclipse and go to Project Facets and change the java or the corresponding Project Facets to the version that it was developed.

Right click the project folder --> Properties --> Project Facets --> Change java version or tick the required module choosing the version.

Comment: Thanks. I had already solved it by time I saw this message but I will try this next time.

Comment: For me was something similar. From Project Facets I selected Runtime tab, then I unchecked the selected Runtime and after did the same , but checked the runtime and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 6):

I resolved it this time with
Right click --> Project --> Properties --> Target Runtimes --> tick the required runtime.
In my case no runtime was selected.

Comment: Worked for me, although I had a runtime selected.  As I had more runtimes available, I selected another and the problem was gone.  Then I reverted to the original.

Answer (score 3):

not sure why it even looks for facets in my case since i don't use it, was solved for me by going to project facets, ticking one facet and then apply then removing the facet then apply again

Comment: In my case, solved in changing java facet from 1.6 to 1.7 and then back again.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers, I had this issue when I renamed a project, then deleted it from the eclipse workspace, then named it back and imported it back into my workspace to fix another issue I was having.

It was an Angularjs project.  I had to select the javascript and Static Web Module facets and that solved the problem.

Follow the same procedure: right click on the project -- properties -- project facets.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Tool Suite v3.9.0.RELEASE you can fix this error by doing the following:

Right-click on project --> Spring Tools --> Enable Spring Aspects Tooling

Answer (score 0):

I have just had the same problem - caused in my case by attempting to revert local changes through SVN.

I was able to resolve within Eclipse by **right clicking a project**, select **Maven**, select **Update Project**, and **Select All** projects.

This avoided having to reimport any code, and work smoothly for all sub-projects.

Hope this helps!